# What brands offer single wrapped vegan chocolates in Southeast USA?

Tags: veganism, food

My office typically purchases a bag of mixed chocolate candies such as Hershey's, Snickers, KitKat etc.

My office manager is looking to provide vegan chocolate options as well.

Vegan chocolate bars are easy to find, but single wrapped servings seem trickier.

We are located in Southeast USA so options for this region are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Raaka chocolate mini dose bars come in an variety of flavors and are available at Amazon and Whole Foods. You can get a box of 30 for 35 dollars.